# loop through dataframe and export different csvs based on values in column

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, group-by, export-to-csv

I'd like to loop through this dataframe and export different csvs based on the parm column group of unique strings (BMP_ASR1 and WATSYRIN), and name the csv from that string group (BMP_ASR1 and WATSYRIN).

```
     name      post_mean    post_stdev  post_lower_bound    post_upper_bound    Year    parm
0   BMP_ASR1    16.50       21.46260    -26.42530        59.4253                2020    BMP_ASR1
1   BMP_ASR1    36.60       53.48860    -70.37730        143.5770               2030    BMP_ASR1
2   WATSYRIN    10390.20    279.44300   9831.31000       10949.1000             2070    WATSYRIN
3   WATSYRIN    11164.90    293.37900   10578.10000      11751.7000             2080    WATSYRIN
4   WATSYRIN    33630.70    902.58200   31825.50000      35435.8000             2090    WATSYRI
```

The output would include all the columns, but with the same values from the parm rows.

```
BMP_ASR1.csv =

         name      post_mean    post_stdev  post_lower_bound    post_upper_bound    Year    parm
    0   BMP_ASR1    16.50       21.46260    -26.42530        59.4253                2020    BMP_ASR1
    1   BMP_ASR1    36.60       53.48860    -70.37730        143.5770               2030    BMP_ASR1

    WATSYRIN.csv =
    
WATSYRIN
    3   WATSYRIN    11164.90    293.37900   10578.10000      11751.7000             2080    WATSYRIN
    4   WATSYRIN    33630.70    902.58200   31825.50000      35435.8000             2090    WATSYRI
```

Answer (score 0):

User groupby and loop through each groupby object

```
lst = ['BMP_ASR1', 'WATSYRIN'] # list of parms to keep
for k,v in df.groupby('parm'): # for key, value in the groupby object
    if k in lst: # if the key is in the list
        v.to_csv(f'{k}.csv', index=False) # write to csv file
```

or filter first and avoid the if statement

```
lst = ['BMP_ASR1', 'WATSYRIN'] # list of parms to keep
filter_df = df[df['parm'].isin(lst)] # boolean indexing to keep certain parms
for k,v in filter_df.groupby('parm'): # for key, value in the groupby object
    v.to_csv(f'{k}.csv', index=False) # value to csv
```

If you want to keep all the unique groups from the parm column then

```
for k,v in df.groupby('parm'):
        v.to_csv(f'{k}.csv', index=False)
```